# External Thunderbolt Display HiDPI resolution (Retina)

Tags: display, thunderbolt, resolution, thunderbolt-display

I have a MacBookPro running Catalina with an external Apple Thunderbolt Display. I have connected to it using a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 adapter.

When the lid of the MacBookPro is open, I can mirror the screen and get an HiDPI resolution of 1920x1200 in the Thunderbolt Display.

When I close the lid of the MacBookPro (which is my preferred arrangement), the maximum HiDPI resolution I can select is 1280x800. The maximum resolution of the Thunderbolt Display I can select is 2560x1600, which is too fuzzy and the text is too small. The maximum resolution of the display is 2560x1440 according to the "About this Mac" report.

My question is, how can I get to the 1920x1200 HiDPI resolution when the MacBookPro lid is closed?

I have tried SwitchResX, but it can't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried SwitchResX? https://www.madrau.com/

Comment: Yes, I have tried SwitchResX. I have also exchanged emails with their customer support. They were unable to solve the problem.